# how to add data in a table dynamically from an array using javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart

```
var main = document.querySelector("#main");//SELECTION OF id//
   //Array of items//
var arr = [
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596552183299-000ef779e88d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80",name:"Microwave",category:"electronics",price:"$300"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588854337115-1c67d9247e4d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",name:"Refrigerator",category:"electronics",price:"$500"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1461151304267-38535e780c79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=890&q=80",name:"Television",category:"electronics",price:"$600"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619017098958-57b1e2d275e4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80",name:"Mobile",category:"electronics",price:"$1000"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525825691042-e14d9042fc70?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80",name:"Earpodes",category:"electronics",price:"$100"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496181133206-80ce9b88a853?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80",name:"Laptop",category:"electronics",price:"$2000"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611186871348-b1ce696e52c9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",name:"Macbook",category:"electronics",price:"$10000"}
]
```

//showing product list //
function show() {
var temp = ``;
arr.forEach(function (elem,index) {
temp+=  `<div class="card"> <div id="circle"> <img src="${elem.img}"> </div> <div id="txt"> <h4>${elem.name}</h4> <h6>${elem.category}</h6> <h3>${elem.price}</h3> </div> <div  id="btn"> <button id="${index}" class="twobtn">Cart</button> <h4>${elem.cartnumber}</h4> </div> </div>`
})
document.querySelector("#main").innerHTML = temp;
}
function cart() {
main.addEventListener('click', function (dets) {
var id = dets.target.id;
//     if (localStorage.getItem('msgs') === null) {
//         updatelocalstorage(arr);
// show(arr);
//     }
//     else {

```
    //         updatelocalstorage(id)
    //         show(id);
    //     }
         arr[id].cartnumber++;
        show();
    })
}
//inserting data in table for bill//
function showbill() {
   
    main.addEventListener('click', function (dets) {
        var template = ``;
        if ((dets.target.id) === arr[dets.target.id]) {
           
        }
        else {
             arr.forEach(function (elem) {
                template += ` <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>${elem.name}</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>${elem.price}</td>
                </tr>`
            })
            document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = template;
        }
         })
    }
```

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and explain the problems you have with your approach -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of adding an array data to a table using vanilla javascript. I have one function written to transform an object from the given array into a `tr` element. Then, I just loop through all the items in the array, and put each row onto the table element. Depending on how you want the style to look there are many options for how to display the image.

Hopefully this helps

```js
const $ = str => [...document.querySelectorAll(str)];

var arr = [
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596552183299-000ef779e88d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80",name:"Microwave",category:"electronics",price:"$300"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588854337115-1c67d9247e4d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",name:"Refrigerator",category:"electronics",price:"$500"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1461151304267-38535e780c79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=890&q=80",name:"Television",category:"electronics",price:"$600"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619017098958-57b1e2d275e4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80",name:"Mobile",category:"electronics",price:"$1000"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525825691042-e14d9042fc70?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=753&q=80",name:"Earpodes",category:"electronics",price:"$100"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496181133206-80ce9b88a853?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80",name:"Laptop",category:"electronics",price:"$2000"},
    {cartnumber:"0", img:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611186871348-b1ce696e52c9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",name:"Macbook",category:"electronics",price:"$10000"}
]

function itemToRow(item) {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  const imgTd = document.createElement("td");
  imgTd.style.cssText += `
    background-image: url(${item.img});
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  `;
  tr.appendChild(imgTd);
  
  const cartNumberTd = document.createElement("td");
  cartNumberTd.textContent = item.cartnumber;
  tr.appendChild(cartNumberTd);
  
  const priceTd = document.createElement("td");
  priceTd.textContent = item.price;
  tr.appendChild(priceTd);
  
  const nameTd = document.createElement("td");
  nameTd.textContent = item.name;
  tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  
  const categoryTd = document.createElement("td");
  categoryTd.textContent = item.category;
  tr.appendChild(categoryTd);
  
  return tr;
}


const table = $("tbody")[0];
for (item of arr) {
  const tr = itemToRow(item);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  min-width: 3rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Img</th>
    <th>Cart #</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```